# Hide title bar on WPF User Control

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I am looking to see if it is possible to hide the title bar and close button on a WPF User Control window.

I cannot use the WindowStyle="None" as this only relates to a window and not a User Control.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn off the title bar of the window on which the user control resides, you can add this to the code of the user control:

```
// walk up the tree to get the parent window
FrameworkElement parent = this.Parent;
while(parent != null && !parent is Window)
{
    parent = parent.Parent;
}

// if window found, set style
if(parent != null && parent is Window)
{
    parent.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Cheers.